# How can i connect Microsoft Frontpage 2003 to CQ5 Repository via WebDav?

Tags: webdav, aem, frontpage, filelock

i have a little problem.

I need to connect Microsoft Frontpage 2003 to CQ5 Repository via WebDav keeping the functions of competitive access (check-in, check-out, file lock).

Someone have any idea?